# How to install Canon MX922 printer?

Tags: printing, canon

I could not find an appropriate driver for the printer. Tried other Canon drivers; a generic Postscript and generic PCL5/6 but when I send a print job, the printer wakes up but does not print.
The same happens when using wireless or USB connection.
Other Canon printers work just fine.

Answer (score 5):

Install the driver from Canon (ver 3.90). Oddly, it shows up on its Asia site, but not on its US site. This worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty.

http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100517002.html

This driver was also linked by this [Technosophy blog](http://technosopher.wordpress.com/2013/06/26/ubuntu-debian-linux-drivers-for-the-canon-mx-922-and-other-mx-series-multifunctions/)

Comment: It appears that [the drivers now show on the Canon USA site](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/inkjet-multifunction/mx-series-inkjet/mx922). As a bonus, they are open-source.

Comment: Canon is incredibly screwy. Now they _don't_ again if your OS autodetects as "Linux 64bit" or "Linux 32bit" (as most will); you have to manually change to just "Linux", at which point the software list (debs, rpms, and source; printing and scanning) will reveal itself under "Drivers".

Comment: I had an older Canon that supported Duplex printing regarding hardware capability.  But The best Linux driver I could track down for it did not include that feature.  So follow-up question.  Does the Linux driver support all the features including Duplex printing?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

MX920 series IJ [Printer Driver](https://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100517002.html) Ver. 3.90 for Linux (debian Packagearchive).

MX920 series [ScanGear MP](https://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100690502.html) Ver. 2.10 for Linux (debian Packagearchive)

Comment: The links above are broken as of 10 Oct 2018.  Do you have an update?

Comment: @JimParker Thanks for the comment.  Links have been updated.

Answer (score 2):

The official drivers from Canon are here:

- IJ Printer Driver - http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100517002.html
- ScanGear MP Driver - http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100518302.html

For some reason, these drivers are only available on the Asia site.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what appeared to fix it for me, a total noob, (I don't know which parts of this procedure may be red herrings):

- Download the driver from the canon-asia site, the US one did not have it.
- Unzip the tar.gz (I thought it was weird that the driver is not a .deb file, it is just a folder that ends in -deb)
- But I cd'd into that folder, and did  sudo ./install.sh

Then in synaptic package manager I made sure that all these were installed:

- cnijfilter2
- cups-backend-bjnp
- printer-driver-gutenprint

Then when I reinstalled my printer for the 100th time,
it gave me a Model called Canon MX920 series PS+Gutenprint v5.3.3.

Hope that helps somebody.